# Rendering NSString to monochrome texture on OSX

Tags: macos, opengl

I want to render an NSString to a monochrome OpenGL texture. I found many examples on how to to that on iOS, but I'm struggling to find a code snippet that works on OSX.

I know how to do the last bit, uploading a texture to the GPU, but how do I get the raw (8 bit per pixel) data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [GLString.m](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Listings/GLString_m.html) in Apple's [Cocoa OpenGL code sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CocoaGL/Introduction/Intro.html). You can easily modify it to generate a monochrome texture. The relevant modifications result in code that looks like so:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:NULL pixelsWide:frameSize.width pixelsHigh:frameSize.height
    bitsPerSample:8 samplesPerPixel:1 hasAlpha:NO isPlanar:NO colorSpaceName:NSDeviceWhiteColorSpace bitmapFormat:0 bytesPerRow:frameSize.width bitsPerPixel:8];

NSGraphicsContext *context = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bitmap];
[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:context];

…    

[string drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(marginSize.width, marginSize.height)]; // draw at offset position

…

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

if (0 == texName)
    glGenTextures (1, &texName);

glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, texName);
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, 0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [bitmap bitmapData]);
```

The key parts are:

1. Allocate your own NSBitmapImageRep with the desired format.
2. Allocate an NSGraphicsContext that writes in to your NSBitmapImageRep.
3. Draw your string.
4. Restore the graphics context to its original state.
5. Call glTexSubImage2D with a pixel format that is compatible with the format you initialized your NSBitmapImageRep to.

Comment: That example is generating an RGB texture. I want a monochrome one.

Comment: That's easy enough to do using NSBitmapImageRep more directly. I've expanded on how to do this in the answer.

Comment: Thank! Is it possible that drawAtPoint is depreciated?

Comment: `-drawAtPoint` isn't deprecated. Note that it is a method on `NSAttributedString` since attributes like font and size are needed in order to draw the string.

Comment: Thanks again. I think I finally found the underlaying issue (NPOTS).